# C# json deserialize to (this) inside object

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to get an object to deserialize into itself. I have tride the following:-

```
   public class JobID
    {
        public string jobname;
        public string first;
        public string second;
        public string third;
        public string clientName;
        public string workflow;
    }

    public void load(string fname)
    {
        string s = File.ReadAllText(fname);
        this = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobID>(s);    
    }
```

But the word this is 'read only' according to the error I get.
I have used 'this.jobname = "X";' before so clearly 'this' is not read only.
I am using Newtonsof.Json.

Comment: C and C# are two different languages. Please use correct tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use static method to load the object. Such as :

```
public class JobID
{
    public string jobname;
    public string first;
    public string second;
    public string third;
    public string clientName;
    public string workflow;
    public static JobId Load(string fname){
        string s = File.ReadAllText(fname);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobID>(s);    
    }
}
```

Comment: I learnt something new - at least how to use static in this way - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can assign a value to a property of 'this', you can't change the object to which 'this' refers to.

The 'this' keyword refers to the current object instance in the context (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this).

Assuming the Load function is inside another object (or static), you could do something like:

```
 public class JobID
{
    public string jobname;
    public string first;
    public string second;
    public string third;
    public string clientName;
    public string workflow;
}

public class JobReader
{
 // Property to store deserialized object
 public JobID Job { get; set; }

 public void load(string fname)
 {
     string s = File.ReadAllText(fname);

     // Assign object to property.
     this.JobID = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobID>(s);    
 }
}
```

Comment: I understand now, because JsonConvert creates the object, not just populating it. (Light goes on!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static method as suggested by Xbotter to create a new instance. But for some reason if you want to deserialize the file content into current object only, then easiest way would be:

```
public class JobID
{
    public string jobname;
    public string first;
    public string second;
    public string third;
    public string clientName;
    public string workflow;

    public void load(string fname)
    {
        string s = File.ReadAllText(fname);
        JobID tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobID>(s);
        copy(tmp);
    }

    public void copy(JobID tmp)
    {
        this.jobname = tmp.jobname;
        // do the same for other properties that you want to copy
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without a static method, you can use the [JsonSerializer.Populate method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm). Example code:

```
public class JobID
{
    public string jobname;
    public string first;
    public string second;
    public string third;
    public string clientName;
    public string workflow;

    public void load(string fname)
    {
        string s = File.ReadAllText(fname);
        new JsonSerializer().Populate(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(s)), this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anssssss provided the answer I've been looking for years. Thank you!
This is how I used it:

```
        bool bOk = false;
        StreamReader myFileStream = null;
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer mySerializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();

        try
        {
            myFileStream = File.OpenText(sFilePath);

            mySerializer.Populate(myFileStream, this);

            bOk = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string sException = e.ToString();
            CHelper.ThrowException(new Exception(sException + "\n\n" + sFilePath));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myFileStream != null)
            {
                myFileStream.Close();
            }
        }

        return bOk;
```